# jQuery autocomplete returns some null values

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, database

I'm using jQuery autocomplete with PHP source file that connects to MySQL and get the info to show as autocomplete on input field. Here's my code:

**Index/Input**

```
<script>

 $(function() {
     $("#search").autocomplete({
    source: 'http://localhost/testes/autocomplete.php',
    minLength: 3
 });
});

</script>

<input type="text" id="search"/>
```

**autocomplete PHP**

```
$req = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM faculty WHERE name LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%'"; 
$query = mysql_query($req);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $results[] = array('label' => $row['name']);
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

The problem is, it returns good values and other null values. But, in the last case, the values should not be null because they are in the database.

For example, in the database I have the entries:
ISCTE - Instituto Universitário
INDEG-ISCTE Business School

Searching by 'iscte' the autocomplete gives second one but the first one appear as null.

Thank you for you time,
Regards,
Hugo

Comment: I don't see where you are giving the parameters to the PHP file

Comment: An aside: Please make sure you escape your sql query properly, otherwise you make yourself vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Gevious, thank you. I'm just testing autocomplete with focus on jQuery. Actually, in the website, we escape our queries.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the encoding. Use this:

```
...
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $results[] = array('label' => utf8_encode($row['name']));
}
...
```

Your database should set to UTF8, but by the way, this fix it.